# How to get following output in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

How to emulate this Sql query:

```
Select A.FID, A.SLNO, A.Date as FromDate, A1.Date ToDate
From #Test A
Inner Join #Test A1 On A.FID = A1.FID And A1.SLNO = A.SLNO + 1
```

Which gives:

[image]

To give the same output using this query:

```
var results2 = from table1 in dtSplitDates.AsEnumerable()
join table2 in dtSplitDates.AsEnumerable() on new { FID = table1.Field<int>("FID"), SLNO = table1.Field<int>("SLNO")} equals new { FID = table2.Field<int>("FID"), SLNO = table2.Field<int>("SLNO") }  into lj
from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
select dtSplitDates2.LoadDataRow(new object[]
{
    r["FID"],
    r["SLNO"],
    r == null ? string.Empty : r["Dates"]
}, false);
```

I am unable to modify my select list and join condition - when i try i get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` There are 2 tables `dtSplitDates` and `dtSplitDates2`

This is how the table `dtSplitDates` looks now and `dtSplitDates2` is its clone:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

will return null without parameter. Pass some default value.

Answer (score 0):

What is dtSplitDates2 ?

Can you please share your table contents.

But what I understood, I would prefer this solution

```
     var results2 = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                       join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on new { FID = table1.Field<int>("FID"), SLNO = table1.Field<int>("SLNO") } equals new { FID = table2.Field<int>("FID"), SLNO = table2.Field<int>("SLNO") } into lj
                       from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new
                       {
                           FID = r["FID"],
                           SLNO = r["SLNO"],
                           Dates = r == null ? string.Empty : r["Date"]
                       };
```